# Send entire Blob data to web hook endpoint

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Am storing all the xml files in azure blob storage. The file data is huge.The Blob events (Created) payload only contains the information about file properties and not the actual data.

Can you please suggest a way to push the entire blob data to a webhook endpoint  automatically for each creation of blob.

Is it ideal to send the entire data to webhook as my data is very large ?

Comment: you have the url of the file in the payload so from your code you should download the file

Comment: Yes... I have the Url to download.But just wanted to check is there a way to send the data itself as part of the webhook.

Comment: No there is no way from he webhook, the webhook notifies you that somethng happens then based on the event you can do whatever you want :-)